# How may I get hold of U+210B?

Tags: symbols, unicode

When I try to insert and compile the symbol, I just get the error message:

> Unicode character ℋ (U+210B) not set up for use with LaTeX. ℋ

How may the problem be resolved?

P.S. Other Unicode symbols work as intended.

---

A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article} \begin{document} ℋ \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show your example code? It might be that the symbol does not exist in the font you use.

Comment: @mickep What is an example code? Do you want to see parts of the preamble?

Comment: It helps if you show a small example, yes. Difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: @mickep This is sufficient for it to not compile, as I indicated, with me:

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
ℋ
\end{document}  P.S. Code used: (U+210B)

Comment: Well, now you got an answer with a way to get some kind of script H, but we still do not know if that is the one you look for... In any case, a problem with your example code is that the H is not in math mode.

Comment: @mickep Adding \(\) or $$ does not help. "Well, now you got an answer with a way to get some kind of script H, ..." It would be better to obtain Unicode's way, so as to be prepared for similar problems down the road.

Comment: @Sapiens it is not clear what you mean by "It would be better to obtain Unicode's way," You have chosen to use pdflatex which has  a pre-unicode font system with at most 256 characters in a font, and most math fonts having only 128 characters. Then you ask for character number 8219. It is surely not surprising that such characters are not set up by default and you need to approximate the ones you use by defining a mapping to a different character in a different font, so H in a script font here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So would I evade the problem if I were to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: well with luatex (via unicode-math) you can directly access fonts that have a ℋ character as shown in Clara's answer so using fonts with 10s of thousands of characters rather than 127 characters does make the problem easier. You still have to choose which font you want though, and it is impossible to use the same font for all of Unicode. Unicode has more characters than can be held in a single OpenType font. Each font just covers a specific Unicode range

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the advice! My document is difficult to move from pdflatex at this point, I believe, on account of its length, or complexity.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `pdflatex`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{H}$
\end{document}
```

Or

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{210B}{$\mathscr{H}$}
\begin{document}
ℋ
\end{document}
```

Or

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{210B}{\mathscr{H}}
\begin{document}
$ℋ$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `unicode-math` with `xelatex`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{H}$
\end{document}
```

Or

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$ℋ$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! At this point I was trouble shooting to make Unicode work. Perhaps someone should write the leaflet "How to LaTeX everything which Unicode provides  that you want".

Comment: +1 but I definitely wouldn't put the dollar signs in `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. WIth them it will be impossible to use the character in math mode.

Comment: @Clara My problem with Unicode still remains, of course, and I would have liked it to be resolved in order to find solutions if I encounter similar solutions in the future.

Comment: Not +1 for exactly the same reason as campa's pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

If you use OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
$ℋ$
\bye
```

or you can use `\fontfam[termes]` or `\fontfam[stix]` or whatever else.